# Kids' book about a boy in parallel universes

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

**Media:** Children's book.

**Cover:** It had a 2D drawing of the kid and maybe some planets on the cover.

**Year read:** 2009-2012 (as a kid in kindergarten to second grade). Written sometime between 2000 and 2012.

**Tone:** Lighthearted, humorous.

**Setting:** Earth, alternate universes, other planets. In the universes/planets there were definitely alien characters with very long and strange names.

**Characters:**
A boy who somehow moves between parallel universes and/or planets.
An alien known as “Mr.” and then an unknown, very long, last name.

**Language:** It was in English and not translated, probably written by an American author.

**Other:** I think it might have been illustrated. It had multiple chapters.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as a plotline for the story, or specific episodes within it that you can recall? I strongly urge you to read [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and add as much information as you can to help us help you identify the story you're looking for.

Comment: @Jeff I think the aliens’ names were rather long and one of them was referred to as “Mr.” something